# adding graphs to en existing graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function that returns a sample of Brownian motion as a result which is in form of data.frame odd columns are the times of each sample and even columns are the data corresponding to the previous time column.
I also have a function that graphs the result of a single motion(two consecutive columns) I want to add all the graphs to one general graph using the  following function

```
Plot_a_Sample_of_Brownian_Motions <- function(Mdata, SampleSize){
  Mdata <- as.matrix(Mdata)
  sum <- 0
  g <- Plot_a_brownian_motion(Mdata[,c(1,2)])
  for (i in 2:SampleSize) {
    x1 <- (2*i) -1
    y1 <- (2*i)
    g <- g + geom_line(aes(x = Mdata[,x1], y = Mdata[,y1]))
  }
  g
}
```

but when I run the code for example for 5 samples the results consist of two of the motions at the time.
like the following
[result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVbJG.png)

and not all together, I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this problem.

I was expecting all of the motions on the same plot.

Comment: You are running in the pitfalls of lazy evaluation. To prevent that the ggplot2 way of adding multiple layers would be to use a list, i.e. use lapply instead of a for loop or vene better reshape your data and use just one geom_line. See e.g. [R loop not changing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524974/12993861) for an example of both approaches.

Comment: I also recommend reshaping your data and using a single `geom_line` call, and just not bothering with the for loop.

Comment: thanks very much I used lapply and it worked.